# How to make wallpaper fit the screen android java?

Tags: java, android, android-wallpaper, wallpapermanager

I Fetch Images from firebase database how can i make the wallpapers fit the screen i have tried the fitScale:XY but didnt work alos the function createdBitmap.

the problem is not with firebase I want to fit the image to the screen size of any device.

How can I convert the int (position) into something Bitmap can read if the solution is with the bitmap functions.

```
private void clickListener() {
        adapter.onDataPass(new SwiperAdapter.onDataPass() {
            @Override
            public void onImageSave(int position, Bitmap bitmap) {
                Dexter.withContext(SwiperActivity.this)
                        .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport multiplePermissionsReport) {
                                if (multiplePermissionsReport.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                                    saveImage(bitmap);
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(SwiperActivity.this, "please allow permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> list, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                                permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                            }
                        })
                        .check();
            }

            @Override
            public void onApplyImage(int position, Bitmap bitmap) {
                WallpaperManager manager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                Toast.makeText(SwiperActivity.this,"Wallpaper successfully set",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    manager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(SwiperActivity.this,"Failed to set as wallpaper", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

```
private void clickListener(int position){
            saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    dataPass.onImageSave(position,bitmap);
                }
            });

            applyWallBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    dataPass.onApplyImage(position,bitmap);
                }
            });
        }
```

I want the images to fit the screen
I have tried many solutions none of them worked like fitScale:XY and the createBitmap function idk what is the problem?